# READ BQUERY STREAMING (real time) API

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-api

I have BigQuery data warehouse which gets its data from Google Analytics.
the data is streamd - real time.
now I want to get this data as it arrives (and not after) to the bigquery using its API.

I have seen the api which lets you query the data after it saved into the bigquery,
for example:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

query = """
    SELECT name, SUM(number) as total_people
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013`
    WHERE state = 'TX'
    GROUP BY name, state
    ORDER BY total_people DESC
    LIMIT 20
"""
query_job = client.query(query)  # Make an API request.

print("The query data:")
for row in query_job:
    # Row values can be accessed by field name or index.
    print("name={}, count={}".format(row[0], row["total_people"]))
```

Is there any way to "listen" to the data and store some of it on cloud?
rather than let it be saved and then query from the bigquery?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently a streaming read mechanism for accessing managed data in BigQuery; existing mechanisms leverage some form of snapshot-like consistency at a given point in time (tabledata.list, storage API read, etc).

Given that your data is already automatically delivered into BigQuery, the next best thing is likely some kind of delta strategy where you read periodically with some kind of filter (recent data filtered by a timestamp, etc).