# Google BigQuery stream to PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql, google-bigquery, stream

I'm using Google BigQuery for OLAP, and plan to provision Google Cloud SQL (Postgres) for OLTP.
My plan is to direct stream data from Google BigQuery to Postgres.
I try googling the solution, but the option is only using batch file .

Is it possible for the streaming solution from Google BigQuery to PostgreSQL?

Comment: Streaming is generally used for real time data. could you explain why you are going for a streaming solution in your case?

Comment: Hi @SakshiGatyan, thank you for your response. The postgresql is going to be used by front end application, so we need near realtime data

Comment: You want to read real time streaming data from BQ to cloud SQL? pls correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes correct @SakshiGatyan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Currently there is no streaming read mechanism for accessing bigquery data* as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71314897/) Stackoverflow post.

Hence, you'll have to go for reading data through batch process.
You can also setup manual ETL process to integrate BigQuery to PostgreSQL using Cloud Data Fusion as mentioned in this [article](https://hevodata.com/learn/bigquery-to-postgresql/#Method_1_Manual_ETL_Process_to_Set_Up_BigQuery_to_PostgreSQL_Integration).